# Disable writeback cache throttling - tuning vm.dirty_ratio

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk, cache

I have a workload with extremely high write burst rates for short periods of times. The target disks are rather slow, but I have plenty of RAM and very tolerant to instantaneous data loss.

I've tried tuning vm.dirty_ratio to maximize the use of free RAM space to be used for dirty pages.

```
# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            251           7         213           3          30         239
Swap:             0           0           0

# sysctl -a | grep -i dirty
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 90000
vm.dirty_ratio = 90
```

However, it seems I'm still encountering some writeback throttling based on the underlying disk speed. How can I disable this?

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/me/foo.txt bs=4K count=100000 oflag=nonblock
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
409600000 bytes (410 MB) copied, 10.2175 s, 40.1 MB/s
```

As long as there is free memory and the dirty ratio has not yet been exceeded - I'd like to write at full speed to the page cache.

Comment: does foo.txt exist before you run `dd`?  I had some weirdness based on that.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264023/confused-about-dd-write-speed-and-vfs-page-cache/483788#483788

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the dirty-throttling, but the immediate syncing. You can check it with the `bo` column in `vmstat 1` - I get:

```
   -----io----
   bi    bo
    0     0
    0     0
    0  4000
    0     0
    ...
```

after `dd if=/dev/zero of=16/test bs=4k count=1000`. (The vmstat output is just 1K-"units" - /proc/diskstats has 512B-units)

Adding `conv=notrunc` avoids that, as does a `rm` before. See sourcejedi's comment.

The ext4 mount option **`noauto_da_alloc`** exactly is meant for that: no extra `sync` for these "write-file-anew" operations. `man ext4` has some good examples. The question goes back to what should "write" or "save" file mean in an editor, and how to make that (power-) fail-safe.

---

You can also check the other side: the dirty pages growing:

```
]# grep nr_dirty /proc/vmstat      
nr_dirty 7886
nr_dirty_threshold 427666
nr_dirty_background_threshold 170815
```

The thresholds are the ratios applied to the current available memory. Only since I quite disabled the periodic writebacks I see more than a dozen dirty pages.

---

### vim

It is really a complex situation; vim has at least two crucial options: `fs` and `wb`: filesync after write and overwrite via backup.

On ext2 it is enough to set `nofs` in vim. On ext4 (with default delayed allocation) the `noauto_da_alloc` mount option is also needed to prevent an immediate syncing, this time by the filesystem.

(with `dd` you have the option to (over)write only a part of a file, unlike `cp` or `vim`)